# Make function available onClick and onKeypress JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

I would like to make my function available for user if they click on the button but if they press enter as well. Here is example:

```js
$('#searchBtn').on('click', function searchUser(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'Components/Application.cfc?method=findUser',
      data: {'searchFldVal':searchFldVal},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(obj){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
        });

        return false;
      }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert(errorThrown);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="searchUser()">
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="searchFld" id="searchFld" size="24" maxlength="24" value="" title="Maximum size of the field is 24 characters." placeholder="Example: John, Miller" />
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"/>
 </div>
</form>
```

Code above works fine if I click on button but if I enter few letters and press enter my page will reload. This file is saved as `.cfm` file. I would like to run `searchUser()` function on both `onClick` and `onKeypress`. If anyone knows how this can be achieved please let me know.

Comment: Just a heads up, the code as presented has errors in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, do not use inline event handlers. Define the function and call it when the form is being submitted as below:

```js
function searchUser(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert ("Do your ajax here instead of alert...");
}

$("#searchForm").on("submit", searchUser);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" action="#" method="POST">
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="searchFld" id="searchFld" size="24" maxlength="24" value="" title="Maximum size of the field is 24 characters." placeholder="Example: John, Miller" />
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="submit" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"/>
 </div>
</form>
```

**Note:**

- removed inline event handler from the form
- changed button type to submit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AJAX to communicate with your server, you might want to leave the method, action, and submit callback off of the form entirely. This is what will cause the default submit behavior of the page reload. Instead, attach a listener to the search field itself, that listens for the enter key press.

```
$('#searchBtn').on('click', searchUser);

$('#searchFld').on('keypress', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.code == 'Enter'){
         searchUser();
    }
}); 


function searchUser(){
    // search for the user
}
```